# EIP register intel architecture

Tags: intel, cpu-architecture

How eip register know the next address to execute?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how variable-length instructions are decoded?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the CPU decodes the instruction (and during this process discovers how long it is), executes it, and then advances the instruction pointer to point to the next instruction. In reality it's a bit more complicated (there are jumps and calls to consider, and things may happen speculatively and/or out-of-order), but the principles hold.